# dat idx files database recognition

Tags: c#, .net, database, odbc, oledb

I have some .dat and .idx files and one .sup file in a directory , and i would like to know if there is any tool or .net programming tecnique to find out what type of database is?

I dont know if this could help, but if i open one .dat file as text file, i get this: 0~0904021846460509040218464605>ÀÀX2Ü

And the common part of all the .dat files, is the following string at the start 0~09040218.

Could you give me a hand?
Thanks a lot.
Kind Regards.
Josema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux has a [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command that uses a listing of [magic numbers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) to try and id a file type. There's a [Win32 port](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) - but I can't vouch for it. Personally, I'd xfer it over to a Linux system and run it there.